# selecting specific string in a field

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I have this file:

```
N104    F1810
N104    F3810
N104    F810
N104    F305
```

and a script to `grep` an input.

Script:

```
enter input
read input
cat file | grep $input
```

when I input “810”, I get the output:

```
N104    F1810
N104    F3810
N104    F810
```

I need the output:

```
N104  F810
```

Comment: input `F810` instead?

Comment: The shortest is with GNU `grep`'s Perl regular expression: `grep -P "\D$input"`. So, what kind of `grep` you have?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E "(^|[^0-9])$input($|[^0-9])" < file
```

That is `$input` preceded by either the beginning of the line or a non-digit, and followed by either the end of the line or a non-digit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also enlist `grep` to do this like this:

```
$ grep "[[:alpha:]]810" sample.txt 
N104    F810
```

More specifically to your use case:

```
$ input=810
$ grep "[[:alpha:]]$input" < sample.txt 
N104    F810
```

I do not know if you expect the `grep` pattern to be able to deal with the 1st column as well, and if so in what capacity.

```
$ input=104
$ grep "[[:alpha:]]$input" < sample.txt 
N104    F1810
N104    F3810
N104    F810
N104    F305
```

This makes use of `grep`'s alphabet character set. Not sure of your requirements, but this will allow you to search on any of the trailing digits in the second column. If you need a more robust solution you'll likely need to change the regular expression.

#### References

- [grep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)